# External disk with bad sector

Tags: hard-drive

I have a 320GB external drive which I use to back up old files. It's pretty full of a load of stuff...

Today when I plugged it into the usual USB port, Ubuntu displayed no files or folders, though when I right-clicked and looked a Properties, it showed 19000+ files totalling ~150GB.

I ran Disks and it showed `Disk is OK, one bad sector`.

I then tried to look at SMART data and got:

```
Error starting SMART Self-Test. sk_disk_smart_self_test: Operation not supported (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

This is as far as my feeble brain can take me (I'm an Ubuntu newbie) - can anyone offer any advice?

Comment: One bad sector is not too much. You can try to repair the file system according to the following link, [Repair the partition table and file system of a pendrive](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986), which should work also with a USB HDD.

Comment: Thanks sudodus.   I've  tried to execute an e2sfck command, but I get this...  joe@joe-Satellite-C660D:~$ sudo e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sdb1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb1

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:

Comment: Good luck and please share the result of your attempt to repair the file system :-)

Comment: I ran out of characters in my last post...  I was going to add: I have no idea what this means; can you/anyone offer advice, please?  Would   ddrescue be a sensible option?

Comment: What file system is there? Linux `ext`, some other linux file system or a Microsoft file system `NTFS`, `FAT32`, or `exFAT`, or a `Mac` file system? This decides which tool to use. `e2fsck` is only for linux `ext2`, `ext3` and `ext4` file systems.

Comment: Use `ddrescue` if you want to clone the drive to another drive of at least the same size in order to do advanced recovery. I think this can wait while you test some other and I hope easier ways to get the drive working again.

Comment: Answering your question, sudodus: it's W95 FAT32 (LBA) - but Windows doesn't find any file system, so I can't use chkdsk.  I hadn't realised e2fsck was for Linux file systems only - that's newbies for you.. :-)

Comment: *Maybe* you can install `dosfstools` and use `dosfsck` according to the details in [Repair the partition table and file system of a pendrive](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986)

Comment: Thanks sudodus; I think I'm sorted now. Sometimes it helps to be clueless :-)

Comment: I installed ddrescue, but got so confused about what I had and hadn't done, I decided to restart the PC. And guess what? My data  became visible - and movable - with the exception of 2 corrupt files. Going to reformat the EDD now. Thanks again for help

Comment: Congratulations:-) You are back on the track again.